# Cut parts of a video from YouTube

Tags: webapp-rec

I uploaded a 10 min video to YouTube, but I am only interested in some "intervals" like the one between minute 4 to 5.

Are there online editors that allow to "cut" it, and upload it to YouTube again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[YouTube itself has an editor](http://www.youtube.com/editor) that can be used with uploaded videos to:

- **Trim clips**
- Combine videos
- Add music
- Insert transitions
- Rotate clips

Answer (score -1):

here is example to CUT with **START** and **END** parameters: 
http://rawgit.com/tazotodua/several-YOUTUBE-PLAYER-SCRIPTS__with_API/master/example99-CUTTER/index.html

Comment: How do I know it is safe to click on that link? Please include the script _in your answer_, so that everyone can see what it does.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use http://viewrz.com/cutter. But it won't be uploaded on YouTube again.